Is there a way to have the window automatically resize once an element is hidden in the layout?
I have two radio buttons. When the .csv button is selected, I want there to only be one input box. when .rsp is selected, I have a new input box appear. It creates space to fit between the radio buttons and the create button. When it disappears, the space remains. Is there a way to get rid of this space when the element is hidden?
import PySimpleGUI as sg

# Define a custom theme for the GUI
my_new_theme = {'BACKGROUND': "#31363b",
                'TEXT': "#f9f1ee",
                'INPUT': "#232629",
                'TEXT_INPUT': "#f9f1ee",
                'SCROLL': "#333a41",
                'BUTTON': ('#31363b', '#0dd1fc'),
                'PROGRESS': ('#f9f1ee', '#31363b'),
                'BORDER': 1,
                'SLIDER_DEPTH': 0,
                'PROGRESS_DEPTH': 0}

# Add and set the custom theme
sg.theme_add_new("MyNewTheme", my_new_theme)
sg.theme("MyNewTheme")
sg.set_options(font=("Helvetica", 12))



layout = [
    [sg.Text("Input mesh name:", pad=(1, 5)), sg.InputText(key="mesh")],

    [sg.Text("Paste boundary conditions below:", pad=(1, 5))],
    [sg.Multiline(key="bound_cond", size=(35, 10), pad=(1, 5))],

    [sg.Radio(".csv", "RADIO1", default=True, key='-CSV-', enable_events=True, pad=(1, 5)),
     sg.Radio(".rsp", "RADIO1", key='-RSP-', enable_events=True, pad=(1, 5))],

    [sg.Text("Select .csv or .rsp file:", size=(17, 1)), sg.Input(), sg.FileBrowse("Choose")],

    [sg.Column([[sg.Text("Auto-assign:", size=(17, 1)), sg.Input(key='-FILE-'),
                 sg.FileBrowse("Choose")]], key='-NODE_FILE-', visible=False, pad=(0, 0))],
    [sg.Button("Create")]
]

window = sg.Window("Input Creation Wizard", layout=layout)

while True:
    event, values = window.read()

    match event:
        case sg.WIN_CLOSED:
            break

        case '-RSP-':
            window['-NODE_FILE-'].update(visible=True)

        case '-CSV-':
            window['-NODE_FILE-'].update(visible=False)

window.close()



Pin's an element provided into a layout so that when it's made invisible and visible again, it will
be in the correct place.  Otherwise it will be placed at the end of its containing window/column.
The element you want to pin is the element that you'll be making visibile/invisible.
The pin helper function also causes containers to shrink to fit the contents correct after something inside has changed visiblity.  Note that setting a hardcoded size on your window can impact this ability to shrink.

To remove the space occupied by a element, you can do it by setting the option vaisible=False, also use the pin helper function to cause containers to shrink to fit the contents correct after something inside has changed visiblity .
    [sg.pin(sg.Column([[sg.Text("Auto-assign:", size=(17, 1)), sg.Input(key='-FILE-'),
                 sg.FileBrowse("Choose")]], key='-NODE_FILE-', visible=False, pad=(0, 0)))],


Am I able to change the text in front of the input that stays in place using the update feature?

Set the key for that Text element, then you can update it by calling window[key].update(...).
